# Why using sync functions in nodejs is known as "blocking the event loop"?

Tags: node.js

If I understand correctly, the EventLoop is the mechanism that node uses to resolve asynchronous operations and then passing them to the call stack, right? My question is, when I use a synchronous method (for example pbkdf2Sync) it will get stuck in the call stack until it is finished but it won't be moved to the EventLoop because is not an async operation, so why is this known as blocking the event loop if in reality it is blocking everything? not JUST the event loop (that as far as I understand, can continue working and will pass the callbacks to the call stack when they're finished)

Is my understanding of the NodeJs inner workins completly wrong? This topic specifically is kinda hard to understand because every resource I read differs in some way or another, so even if I think I get the bigger picture, these are the "details" that confuse me.

Comment: "*so why is this known as blocking the event loop if in reality it is blocking everything?*" event loop = everything. It's not some side mechanism, *all* of the code is run through *one* event loop. If you block it, then no other code would run.

Comment: Oh ok, well this is confusing me more, because every article I read about the event loop only mentions the 4 main phases (I know there are more) like Timers, I/O, setImmediate and closing callbacks. Because of this I had the impression that the event loop was some side mechanism inside libuv. So, in what moment during the event loop is my javascript code executed?

Comment: Well...while it runs. Same as all the other code, really. The event loop picks the next task to execute, runs it to completion then repeats the same process again. Forever. Or until the program is terminated. If your code was executed as reaction to some event, then it would run during that event being processed. If your code sets up reactions to events (handlers), then the handler code would run later. If you write `setTimeout(() => console.log("hello"); syncLoopInSeconds(42)` then the console log is scheduled for later but the sync loop stops everything before anything can be processed

Comment: Yes, it blocks **everything** and part of that everything is the event loop. Most people don't really care that when you do `foo(); bar()` that `foo` is blocking `bar` since `foo` needs to complete before `bar` is called - that's obvious. But people need a terminology for the non-obvious, the fact that `foo` is also blocking all network packets, all UI updates, all timeouts and intervals etc. So we say it blocks the event loop. "Blocking the event loop" means that your code is not processing timers, network I/O, disk I/O etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What is blocking**

> Why using sync functions in nodejs is known as "blocking the event loop"?

In a nutshell, it's because the event loop can only process the next event when you return from whatever your current Javascript is doing and allow the event loop to look for the next event.  A sync function blocks the interpreter until it finishes.  So, the entire time a sync function is working and you're waiting for it to return, the interpreter is blocked and control is not returned back to the event loop. This blocks the event loop and also blocks your Javascript from running.

**Single Thread**

Nodejs runs your Javascript all with a single thread.  Other threads are used internally, but your Javascript itself runs only in a single thread (we're assuming there is no use of WorkerThreads in your code).  So, when you make a synchronous function call, that single thread that runs your Javascript is busy and blocked until the synchronous function call returns and can then continue executing more of your Javascript.

This blocks everything.  It blocks running more of your Javascript after the synchronous function call and it blocks getting back to the event loop to run any other event handlers that are pending such as incoming network events, timers, completion events from other things such as disk I/O, etc...  So, while this is blocking the event loop, it's also blocking running more of your own code after the function call.

**Non-Blocking, Asynchronous Operations**

On the other hand, asynchronous functions such as `fs.readFile()`, for example, don't block.  They initiate their operation and return immediately.  This allows the interpreter to continue running any more of your own Javascript after the call to `fs.readFile()` and it also allows you to return from whatever event triggered your work in the first place which will return control back to the event loop so it can service other waiting events or other events that will trigger in the future.  `fs.readFile()` then does most of its work in native code (behind the scenes) outside of the main thread that runs your Javascript.  So, these type of asynchronous functions don't block the event loop - instead they cooperate with the event loop so that other things can get run while waiting for the completion of the asynchronous operation that was previously initiated.  When they complete, they insert an event into the event loop that causes the event loop to call the completion callback at it's earliest convenience (when it's not blocked).

**Differences in Blocking**

It's also worth noting that functions that represent both synchronous and asynchronous operations both block the execution of your Javascript and block the event loop until they return.  The difference is that an asynchronous operation returns from the function nearly immediately, long before the asynchronous operation itself is complete and communicates its completion and/or eventual result back via a promise, callback or event (which are all callbacks at the lowest level of the event loop).  The synchronous operation does not return until the operation itself is complete.  So, the asynchronous operation only blocks for a very short duration while the operation is being initiated whereas the synchronous operation blocks for the entire duration of the operation (until it completes).

**More About the Event Loop**

> So, in what moment during the event loop is my javascript code executed?

When control returns back to the event loop, it goes through several different phases looking for things to do.  When it finds something to do, that "something" results in calling a Javascript callback that starts running some of your Javascript.  For example if the "something to do" is a `setTimeout()` timer that is ready to fire, then it will call the Javascript callback that was passed to `setTimeout()`.  That callback runs to its completion and only when your Javascript returns from that callback does the event loop regain control and get to look for the next event to run and call its callback.

> it won't be moved to the EventLoop because is not an async operation

This is not really the correct way to think about things.  Things are not really "moved to the event loop".

A synchronous operation is just a blocking function call that returns when it returns and execution of any other Javascript is blocked until that blocking function call returns.  Things are blocked because the single threaded interpreter running your Javascript is stuck waiting for this function to finish.  It can't do anything else and the event loop is also blocked because it can't do anything until the interpreter returns control back to the event loop.

An asynchronous operation, on the other hand, initiates some operation (let's say it issues an http request to some other host) and then immediately returns, long before it has the result of that http request.  Since this asynchronous operation returns before it has its result, it is considered non-blocking and because it returns quickly, you can then return from whatever event caused your code to run and that will then return control back to the event loop.  That allows the event loop to then look for other events to handle and run their corresponding callbacks.  Meanwhile, the asynchronous operation that was previously started has some native code associated with it (that may or may not be running in an native code OS thread - depending upon what type of operation it is).  But regardless, that native code is configured such that when the asynchronous operation completes, it will insert an event into the appropriate event queue.  So, at some future point when nodejs has control back in the event loop, it will find that event and run the Javascript callback associated with that event, thus notifying the original Javascript code that the asynchronous operation is now complete and providing some sort of result or error code.

**Example**

As a simple example, let's say you run this code:

```js
    // timer that wants to fire in 1 second
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("timer fired")
    }, 1000);

    // loop that blocks for 5 seconds
    const start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < 5000) { }
    console.log("blocking loop finished");
```

This will output:

```
blocking loop finished
timer fired
```

Even though the timer was set to run 1 second from now, the `while()` loop blocked everything for 5 seconds so it wasn't until after the `while()` loop finished and returned back to the system that the event loop could look at what it had to do next and call the callback associated with the timer.

This `while` loop is similar to a blocking function such as `pbkdf2Sync()`.  Both block the interpreter and don't return until they are finished and therefore nothing in the event loop gets a chance to run until they are finished.

**A Simple Analogy**

Here's a simple analogy.  Imagine you need to contact your cable company to troubleshoot a problem.  There are two ways for you to get ahold of them.  The first way is that you call them and sit on the phone on hold for an hour waiting for a customer service representative to pick up your call.  You can't really do much else while you're sitting on hold because you have to be right there waiting and ready to respond when someone finally comes on the line to help you.  Thus, you are "blocked" from doing a lot of other things.  **This is a "blocking, synchronous operation".**  You can't really do much else while you're waiting on hold.

The second way you can call the cable company is to request a callback sometime in the future and when a representative is available, they will call you back.  As soon as you're done requesting the callback, you can go about your business doing other things.  You have to be able to answer an incoming call when it arrives, but other than that you're not blocked from doing many other things.  **This is a "non-blocking, asynchronous operation".**

But, if while you're supposed to be able to answer your telephone callback from the second scenario above, you make another call and are on the phone for 30 minutes, the cable company is blocked from reaching you on the phone for the duration of your other call.  In our analogy, you are **"blocking the event loop" during your other call** as the incoming event from the cable company can't be processed while you're on a call.

Comment: big thanks for this clear explanation. I have just a little remark, can you recheck your example about the setTimeout ? I tested it, I got "timer fired" before "blocking loop finished" ...

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA - I moved that code into a snippet so you can run it right here in the answer.  I get "blocking loop finished" before "timer fired".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the snipet ... But I tried it on a node console, I got "timer fired" before "blocking loop finished" ! Weird !

Comment: When I run it in a nodejs program (I hate the nodejs console and never used it because it has lots of weirdness that is not how an actual nodejs program works), I get the same as in my answer.  If you're actually running the correct code, then I think you're seeing one of those console weirdness things.  The console is not reality.

Comment: it must be that, yes! Thanks again :)

Comment: if you run his code in REPL, please wrap the answer in `(function(){ /*answer here*/})()`

Comment: @jfriend00, Im not the owner of the question..

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA - Right you are.